# Why NSDate is reporting the wrong date?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

Here is my code.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];        
NSString *todayString = [[today description] substringToIndex:10];
NSLog(@"Today: %@", todayString);
```

I am getting 2011-07-19 instead of 2011-07-18. Any ideas on what may be the problem?

Comment: What is the timezone you are in and what is the timezone of the device  you are getting the date from?

Comment: also verify the actual system time form the server in the OS.

Comment: My time zone is set to the eastern time zone. The current date on my Mac is `Monday, 18 July, 2011`. Also, I am running my application in the simulator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSDate's `description` method returns times in UTC, which if you are in the US Eastern Time Zone during daylight savings time is 4 hours later than your wall clock time. In other words, at 10pm your time it is 2am the next day in UTC.

The usual way to fix it is to use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead, and explicitly set the time zone if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did.