# convert NSDate to NSString is ok,but reverse is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to change UTC time to local time by NSDateFormatter.

But it doesn't work what I expect.

```
-(NSDateFormatter *)df
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    return dateFormatter;
}


...

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSString *dateStr = [[self df] stringFromDate:now];
// dateStr is correct.
//dateStr is 2013-12-26 20:32:26 +0900

NSLog(@"dateStr is %@",dateStr);

NSDate *date = [[self df] dateFromString:dateStr];
// date is wrong.
//date is 2013-12-26 11:32:26 +0000

NSLog(@"date is %@",date);
```

Why date is not equal to dateStr.

I want date return 2013-12-26 10:32:26 +0900

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or [Why NSDate is reporting the wrong date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741519/why-nsdate-is-reporting-the-wrong-date) (and probably some more ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSDate *date` that you get is correct - `2013-12-26 11:32:26 +0000` is the UTC representation of `2013-12-26 20:32:26 +0900`. `NSDate` objects do not embed the time zone - they represent an abstract point in time, not a point in time at any specific time zone.

`NSLog` always logs time in in UTC, because it calls the `description` method of `NSDate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the time zone of your final Date to get the desired result.

Comment: `NSDate` objects don't have time zones.