# from string to Nsdate Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I get date from MySql database in this form:

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

for example : `19/09/2015 14:39:18`

I want convert this string in NSDate object in Swift , and for this reason I did like this:

```
var d = "19/09/2015 14:39:18"
var form : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
form.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
print(form.dateFromString(d)!)
```

but I get by last print this:

```
2015-09-19 12:39:18 +0000
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why NSDate is reporting the wrong date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741519/why-nsdate-is-reporting-the-wrong-date)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `NSDateFormatter` that the incoming date strings are formatted for the GMT time zone:

```
var d = "19/09/2015 14:39:18"
var form : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
form.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
form.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
print(form.dateFromString(d)!)
```

Prints:

```
"2015-09-19 14:39:18 +0000"
```

If you omit manually setting the `timeZone` property, the `NSDateFormatter` will inherit the current system time zone, and parse it as if it were a *local* format time. Then when you're *printing* the new `NSDate` object, it's being displayed in GMT, which results in the offset.

**Edit:** Once you have your `NSDate` object, you can then use the same formatter to go *back* to a string representation with the same format:

```
var d = "19/09/2015 14:39:18"
var form : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
form.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
form.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
form.stringFromDate(form.dateFromString(d)!) // "19/09/2015 14:39:18"
```

Comment: but it is wrong for me because I want that print 19/09/2015 14:39:18

Comment: Is your question about the hour offset? Or the "+0000" at the end? If the latter, you can simply use `form.stringFromDate(...)`

Comment: my problem is this: I have a string in this format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" for example "19/09/2015 14:39:18", I want create a NSDate object that represents that string (like NSDate) with same format ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Comment: In my code when I print the Nsdata object it isn't the same format of the input string

Comment: Did you try using `stringFromDate()` like I suggested?

Comment: yes and it prints "2015-09-19 14:39:18 +0000" , but I would "19-09-2015 14:39:18 +0000"

Comment: I don't think you're using it properly. See my edit.